# Woocommerce Orders: How to display First Name then Last Name when Previewing?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When i check my orders on my Woocommerce website and click on the preview button I get this popup window displaying the billing and shipping details. As you can see from the shipping details the LASTNAME is displayed first. Is there a way to display first the FIRSTNAME then LASTNAME?

[image]

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with the Japanized for WooCommerce plugin. I disabled it and that seems to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the **plugins > woocommerce > templates > order** and find logic for the shipping address and change the order for the name as you want.

Comment: if your problem has been solved, please don't forget to tick my answer as correct answer. @colofofong